# Why is this code for Selection Sort Algorithm not giving output?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, temp, a[10] = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 }, n = 10;

    printf("Before sorting, the array is:");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        temp = i;

        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[j] < a[temp])
                temp = j;
        }

        if (temp != i) {//for swapping
            a[j] = a[j] + a[temp];
            a[temp] = a[j] - a[temp];
            a[j] = a[j] - a[temp];
        }
    }

    printf("\nAfter sorting, the array is:");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

The Output:

[image]

The sorted values are not being printed. Where are the errors in this code?

Comment: There is no need to post an image of text output from your program. Please inline the text into your post.

Answer (score 0):

The output the code you've listed produces is:

```cpp
Before sorting, the array is:9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
After sorting, the array is:9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 0 4198464
```

link:

https://godbolt.org/z/o3nfz9Yv3

The garbage at the end appears to be a result of this code:

```cpp
        if(temp!=i)
        {//for swapping
            a[j]=a[j]+a[temp];
            a[temp]=a[j]-a[temp];
            a[j]=a[j]-a[temp];
        }
```

When this code executes, `j` is always equal to `n`, which means you are always accessing invalid data on `a[j]`. I think you meant to use 'i' inplace of 'j'.

Answer (score 0):

The output does not appear because you do not print a newline after the numbers.  Some systems require this for proper output.

Note however that the swapping code is incorrect: you should swap `a[temp]` and `a[i]`, not `a[j]`.

Swapping values by adding and subtracting is incorrect: it does not work for floating point values and non numerical types and has undefined behavior for signed integers in case of overflow. You should use a temporary variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, temp;
    int a[10] = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

    printf("Before sorting, the array is:");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf(" %d", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        temp = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[j] < a[temp])
                temp = j;
        }
        if (temp != i) {//for swapping
            int t = a[temp];
            a[temp] = a[i];
            a[i] = t;
        }
    }
    printf("After sorting, the array is:");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf(" %d", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you a have a **simple typo**: you should use `i` index instead of `j` in the **for swapping** fragment:

Current code has `a[j]`, which is *incorrect*, since `j == n` and you try to manipulate with a item which is *out* of `0 .. n - 1` *range*:

```
    if (temp != i) {//for swapping
        a[j] = a[j] + a[temp];    // <- a[j] is in fact a[n] here
        a[temp] = a[j] - a[temp];
        a[j] = a[j] - a[temp];
    }
```

It should be `a[i]`, we swap current `a[i]` and found `a[temp]` items:

```
    if (temp != i) {//for swapping
        a[i] = a[i] + a[temp];
        a[temp] = a[i] - a[temp];
        a[i] = a[i] - a[temp];
    }
```